# Convert a series of values in to a relative 1-10 scale

Tags: scale, average

Let's say I have a few sets of values like this:

Height (in inches):

```
John 72.3
Peter 64.5
Frank 78.5
Susan 65.8
Judy 69.0
Mary 72.7
```

Weight (in pounds):

```
John 212
Peter 232
Frank 140
Susan 355
Judy 105
Mary 76
```

Age (in seconds since birth)

```
John 662256000
Peter 1292976000
Frank 977616000
Susan 1229904000
Judy 599184000
Mary 283824000
```

What's the best way to convert these values into a 1-10 scale relative to the other values?

I want to be able to say John is a 6/10 on height, 10/10 on height, and a 3/10 on age (made up values) for example.

One issue I'd like to be able to avoid is having extreme values on either side distort the system too much. A very heavy or tall person shouldn't distort the entire scale.

Comment: Are you looking for a statistically sound solution, or just the groundwork on how to categorize ranges of values?

Answer (score 1):

In R

```
heightOrder <- order(height)
```

will give you the rank order of each item.  If there are 10 it will go from 1-10.  You could scale that to 10.

```
heightOrder <- heightOrder / max(heightOrder) * 10
```

Now that goes from 0-10.  Although, now that I look at your question you asked "best way".  The best way to scale depends on what you want to accomplish.  You need to add more to your question to really know the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it simply:

```
y = (x-min)/(max-min)*9+1
```

Perhaps with some rounding using

```
sprintf '%.0f'
```

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw( minmax );

my %people = (
   John  => { height => 72.3, weight => 212, age =>  662256000 },
   Peter => { height => 64.5, weight => 232, age => 1292976000 },
   Frank => { height => 78.5, weight => 140, age =>  977616000 },
   Susan => { height => 65.8, weight => 355, age => 1229904000 },
   Judy  => { height => 69.0, weight => 105, age =>  599184000 },
   Mary  => { height => 72.7, weight =>  76, age =>  283824000 },
);

sub scale {
   my ($min, $max, $x) = @_;
   return ($x-$min)/($max-$min)*9+1;
}

my ($min_height, $max_height) = minmax( map $_->{height}, values %people );
my ($min_weight, $max_weight) = minmax( map $_->{weight}, values %people );
my ($min_age,    $max_age   ) = minmax( map $_->{age   }, values %people );

for my $name (keys %people) {
   my $person = $people{$name};
   printf("%-6s  height: %2.0f/10  weight: %2.0f/10  age: %2.0f/10\n",
      "$name:",
      scale($min_height, $max_height, $person->{height}),
      scale($min_weight, $max_weight, $person->{weight}),
      scale($min_age,    $max_age,    $person->{age   }),
   );
}
```

Output:

```
Susan:  height:  2/10  weight: 10/10  age:  9/10
John:   height:  6/10  weight:  5/10  age:  4/10
Mary:   height:  6/10  weight:  1/10  age:  1/10
Judy:   height:  4/10  weight:  2/10  age:  4/10
Peter:  height:  1/10  weight:  6/10  age: 10/10
Frank:  height: 10/10  weight:  3/10  age:  7/10
```

Comment: You said the scale had to be relative.

Comment: With a famous example: "Bill Gates enters a dinner"... If you apply your algorithm to yearly salaries in the room, Bill will get a 10 and every other customer will get a 1. This is what @Pete would like to avoid when he asks: "One issue I'd like to be able to avoid is having extreme values on either side distort the system too much. A very heavy or tall person shouldn't distort the entire scale."

Comment: @flodel, He doesn't want results above 10, and he asked for a relative (proportional, linear) scale. So I would need to ignore one of his requirements to satisfy his wishlist item that outliers don't cause issues.

Comment: @flodel, It's this or nothing. If this isn't what he wants, I probably can't help him because my stats knowledge is non-existent (awful prof).

Comment: relative only means "greater or smaller", it does not necessarily imply a proportional/linear scale. Three people have suggested using quantiles (one was not explicit about it though). That's the right way to go to provide a relative scale that addresses outliers.

Comment: @flodel, What's a "greater or smaller scale"??? He didn't ask for "relative order", he asked for "relative scale".

Answer (score 1):

If you want your sample to be equally distributed within each of your 1, 2, ...10, then I suggest you use quantiles. In R:

```
> relative.scale <- function(x) {
+     percentiles <- quantile(x, probs = seq(0,0.9,0.1))
+     sapply(x, function(v)sum(percentiles <= v))
+ }

> x <- runif(100)
> s <- relative.scale(x)
> table(s)
s
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

Answer (score 1):

In R, you can use `quantile` to find the deciles of the data and then `findInterval` to find the interval in which each observation lies.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
findInterval( x, quantile(x, seq(0,1,length=11))) )
```